# Is there a command to renew dhcp lease for ipmi?

Tags: dhcp, ipmi, bmc

I have updated config of my dhcp server, so that server should get a new ipmi address. But the server stay at its old address for some time. If I do not want to wait, I want to go to the server and force it to ask for the dhcp address. Is there a special command for that?

I know I can make

```
ipmitool bmc reset cold
```

and it works, but just wondering if it is possible without rebooting ipmi.

Comment: Normally change in setting need cold or warm reset for ipmi but conceptually in network when one nework card down and up setting must be renewable . Did you try to down and up your network card ? Also another  ttick  is set fake static ip to a card and again change ip to dhcp again

Comment: Why do you care about rebooting the BMC? rebooting it should have no affect on the running operating system. IF there is a logging aspect then put in a change request, though frankly unless our old lease is a week or something dumb like that you should be fine. Also Why are you running the BMC over DHCP in the first place? It is a SERVER.

Comment: @mohammadmoeini yeah, I also thought about such trick. Maybe even not setting a fake static ip, but just switch address source to static, than back to dhcp. But still it is a trick.

Comment: @RowanHawkins I do not care about rebooting bmc actually, just wondering if there is a way to not do it. Looks like others also do it via bmc resetting...
I have a binding of  bmc mac to a static address in dhcp config. It is ok in my case.

Comment: Typically you'd plan a change like that beforehand and reduce the lease time -- if your standard lease time is 1 day, then you'd reduce it to five minutes on the day before the change, and to ten seconds five minutes before the change, and then you get almost instantaneous switchover from all affected hosts without having to manually poke them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution to rerequest an address for ipmi (at least I have tested it working on Supermicro server).

The trick is to set ip address source to static and then back to dhcp. For example:

```
ipmitool lan set 1 ipsrc static
ipmitool lan set 1 ipsrc dhcp
```

This way is faster than resetting bmc.

Note: a channel number may be different if you use non Supermicro server.

Comment: I find it a bit irritating that this was my answer a year before and you refused the option of doing an interface IP mode change and then made your own answer of doing exactly that, but specific to your motherboard which had never been specified.

Comment: @RowanHawkins Yes, I see. I probably didn't notice it at the time of writing. Sorry. I upvoted your answer to compensate.

Comment: Resetting the BMC did not actually release/renew for me (also SuperMicro). But this did. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to reboot the BMC, you could set it to an invalid static IP and then reset it to DHCP using an OS based tool. How to actually do that depends on the motherboard/BMC and the OS and if special tools are needed by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally change in setting need cold or warm reset for ipmi but conceptually in network You when one network card down and up setting must will be renew.
A Trick is set IP addr to static and back to dhcp setting again